# Discord single message deleter bot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want my Discord bot for single message delete code
i try this code

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === 'say') {
      message.delete (10000);
      message.reply('`say!`').then(d_msg => { 
        d_msg.delete(10000); });
  }
```

but i get this error

> ```
>  throw err;
>   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\muhad\bot.js'
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
>     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
>     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
>   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
>   requireStack: []
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[message.delete()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete) takes an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) as parameter, not an integer, therefore, you **can't** use `message.delete(10000)`.

To fix your code, provide an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) containing the timeout (and optionally, the reason) to the [message.delete()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete) function.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === 'say') {
      message.delete({timeout: 10000});
      message.reply('`say!`').then(d_msg => { 
      d_msg.delete({timeout: 10000})});
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

On my own discord bot i use this snippet :

```
        message.channel.bulkDelete(amount, true).catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            message.channel.send(`there was an error when deleting messages !`);
        });
```

Where amount is a parameter of the `!clear-message` command
**E.G** : `!clear-message 50`